# Watir resize_to don't work anymore

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Hello i've some trouble about windows managing with Watir gem in Ruby.

I've working with watir '6.2.1' until I finished to write my program, and I always got an error that is "Element is not clickable at point (x, y)..." never at the same location, whereas really nothing was on the button that i want to focus.

In this case, i just needed to update watir to don't have this error again.
I think that this error was resolved, but i've the same error, that I already had, when i want to click exactly in the same location as before.

Before i've update watir to the last update, i used 
`browser.window.resize_to(1366, 786)`, it's worked and i did not have the error anymore.

Now, it's not working. My window does not resize anymore.. When i put back the old version, it's the same issue.

I'm sorry about my bad english, i hope that you understand what i want to explain.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Which favor of browser, which version of that browser.  Which version of Watir is working for you and which version is broken?   You mentioned v6.2.1 but did not indicate if that was what worked for you, or what you had issues with.

Comment: Sorry, i'm working with mac os Sierra 10.12.6, i'm using Chrome Version 62.0.3202.89, the Watir version which is broken is the last version ( 6.4.0 ) and the version that worked before updating ( 6.2.1 ).

So, now when i reinstall Watir 6.2.1, it's not working anymore.

I have find another solution, that is to get the href from the button link, and make a `browser.goto('this_href')`, in this case i never could have my issue of element not clickable, with or without resizing of my browser !

Comment: When did you last update your Chromedriver?

Comment: I do not have updated chromedriver, i'm going to try !

Comment: It's work perfectly now ! Thank you so much :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to update your chromedriver.   I get bit by that every so often because the browser will update automatically and without alerting you to that fact..  So it's not uncommon to have the browser get 'ahead' of chromedriver and things stop working or start working in strange weird ways until you realize what is going on and update chromedriver.